# add static key word dynamically before the function

Tags: php

I want to like something :

```
if(true)
 define("M_STATIC", "static");
else 
 define("M_STATIC", "");


class A
{

M_STATIC function() // this is not allowed.
   {
    //do something my task
   }
}
```

I think, you know.... what  i want. :)

> I'm using a CMS. and new version of
>   CMS is changed with some function
>   declaration.(like old cms not have
>   static but new version have) so i
>   think, my page should be compatible
>   both version (this class extends by CMS class and this function is override to parent function )

Answer (score 3):

This is just not possible, actually : a method is `static`, or is not ; but it's something thats defined at compile-time, and not at execution-time.

And, in PHP, there is no pre-processor *(like you'd have in C, for example)*, to do the kind of replacements you are asking.

Comment: I don't think there is -- you might want to go with two methods : one that is static, and the other that is not ? But not sure why you'd want a method to be both static and non-static, actually.

Comment: @Manish what do you need this for?

Comment: @Pekka::I'm using a CMS. and  new version of CMS is changed with some function declaration.(like old cms not have static but new version have) so i think, my page should be compatible both version.

Comment: @Manish ah okay, I see. Hmmmm. I think having two source files is the most viable alternative here... Unless you want to build a pre-processor yourself, which is something I would not recommend.

Comment: @Mr. pekka: thanks for this. Any idea for how to perform my task??

Answer (score 1):

Since the new version is static but the old version wants non-static, I'd define it static and then create an instance method that simply calls the static one for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure doing something like this is possible(Which I do not think so) , even if it is possible ,It is not a good practice in OOP, it will make your code very difficult to understand and adds complexity to it.
I am not sure what you want out of this bit if you want need a static function create a class to hold a static one and another class which holds non static functions.